# Vlookup partial number in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I'm trying to use a vlookup on telephone numbers by looking for the last 8 characters as some are begin 4401 and others just 1.

This is what I have so far:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&(TRUNC(RIGHT(A3*1,8),0)*1),J:N,5,FALSE),"Unknown")
```

Column J contains the phone number and column N contains the source of the call (which is what I'm trying to extract).

The problem I have is that the iferror 'Unknown' is being returned. If I change the numbers to words then it works, it seems that it's numbers that are the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Take off the IFERROR statement and see what the error is.  Right now, you are returning a string.  So how could you tell?

Comment: #N/A is returned when removing the iferror

Comment: Yeah, that's probably not descriptive enough.  What I suggest doing is to hardcode the expected result in a cell, and match that with the cell you are pulling from, and see what you get.  If it doesn't match, it may at least let you know why.

Comment: It seems to break when using the wildcard. It works for text but not numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you willing and able to modify the lookup spreadsheet structure slightly to add a Column K using the formula below in cell K1 and dragging that down??

```
=TEXT(J1,0)
```

Then your VLOOKUP will now see text instead of numbers. Therefore the wildcard will work. Just make sure to move your range accordingly (J:N to K:O).

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP("*"&(TRUNC(RIGHT(A3*1,8),0)*1),K:O,5,FALSE),"Unknown")
```

**Edit:** If you do not wish to modify your structure (probably best not to but case by case), this array formula will do the job. Make sure you hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter after entering the formula. If you don't, everything will return "Unknown". Ctrl+Shift+Enter is how Excel knows it is an array function.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($N:$N,MATCH("y",IF(RIGHT(A3,8)=RIGHT($J:$J,8),"y",),0)),"Unknown")
```

With this latter method, you may want to set some sort of bound on your $J:$J range in order to speed up the function so it isn't checking every row in that column. Pick something bigger than your data will ever be (e.g., $J$1:$J$50000).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
{=INDEX($N$1:$N$4,MATCH(A3&"",RIGHT($J$1:$J$4,8),0),1)}
```

You need to enter it as an array formula - so <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> after keying in the formula.